# Cassandra tombstones can't be cleared

Tags: cassandra-2.0

We have a Cassandra cluster in production that can't stop loging WARN and ERRORS like this :

```
WARN [ReadStage:290753] 2016-04-22 17:00:06,461 SliceQueryFilter.java (line 231) Read 101 live and 33528 tombstone cells in keyspace.tablespace.Events_event_type_idx (see tombstone_warn_threshold). 100 columns was requested, slices=[5347432d45504a2d3535373639333936:2016/04/22 16\:46\:24.186-COMMANDE-ORDER-201655769396001-]

ERROR [ReadStage:290744] 2016-04-22 17:00:07,556 SliceQueryFilter.java (line 206) Scanned over 100000 tombstones in crm.Events.Events_event_type_idx; query aborted (see tombstone_failure_threshold)

ERROR [ReadStage:290729] 2016-04-22 17:00:18,708 SliceQueryFilter.java (line 206) Scanned over 100000 tombstones in crm.Events.Events_event_type_idx; query aborted (see tombstone_failure_threshold)

ERROR [ReadStage:290729] 2016-04-22 17:00:18,709 CassandraDaemon.java (line 258) Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:290729,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.TombstoneOverwhelmingException
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2016)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.TombstoneOverwhelmingException
at    org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.collectReducedColumns(SliceQueryFilter.java:208)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateColumns(QueryFilter.java:122)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateOnDiskAtom(QueryFilter.java:80)
.
.
.

ERROR [ReadStage:290751] 2016-04-22 17:00:30,771 SliceQueryFilter.java (line 206) Scanned over 100000 tombstones in crm.Events.Events_event_type_idx; query aborted (see tombstone_failure_threshold)
```

The setup is : Cassandra 2.0.15, 4 Nodes, Replication 3.
There is no TTL on the data inside this tablespace and de gc_grace was set to 0.

We actually do 'maintenance' every weeks which consist of :

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="/var/log/cassandra/maintenance.log"
echo "----------------------------------------" >> $logfile
echo "$(date) Cassandra cluster maintenance started." >> $logfile
echo "----------------------------------------" >> $logfile

nodetool -h localhost setcompactionthroughput 999
echo "$(date)  Cassandra scrub started." >> $logfile
nodetool -h localhost scrub
echo "$(date)  Cassandra scrub completed." >> $logfile
echo "$(date)  Cassandra repair started." >> $logfile
nodetool -h localhost repair --partitioner-range
echo "$(date)  Cassandra repair completed." >> $logfile
echo "$(date)  Cassandra compaction started." >> $logfile
nodetool -h localhost compact
echo "$(date)  Cassandra compaction completed." >> $logfile
echo "$(date)  Cassandra cleanup started." >> $logfile
nodetool -h localhost cleanup
echo "$(date)  Cassandra cleanup completed." >> $logfile

nodetool -h localhost setcompactionthroughput 16

dt=$SECONDS
ds=$((dt % 60))
dm=$(((dt / 60) % 60))
dh=$((dt / 3600))
printf 'Total Run Time : %d:%02d:%02d' $dh $dm $ds >> $logfile
```

This 'maintenance' does not solve the problem, we tried to do specific actions on the particular Tablespace but it ain't done much.

We tried to set the gc_grace to a higher value then lunch the maintenance script but we had the same result.
I know this is nor really an error but a protection to keep good performances on Cassandra but we are kind in the blur for this one.

Our next step is to dump the entiere tablespace, drop it and then recreate but it seems to be a bit radical for a cluster in production.

Does anyone know what could go wrong for the tombstones cleanup ?

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your maint script is a bit odd. You typically don't want to run a full `nodetool compact` regularly. Cassandra's compaction strategies are smart enough to do the right thing automatically.

That said, your tombstone exception is in `crm.Events.Events_event_type_idx` , which looks like a secondary index on Events(event_type). As you insert/change/delete Event data, that index builds up a ton of tombstones. This is a less common (but not unexpected) edge case in secondary indexes when the distribution of data within the index is different than the distribution in your table - secondary indexes in cassandra work well with a moderate cardinality, but you've got a lot of a certain event type.

The first step in trying to combat this is to `nodetool rebuild_index` for that ks/table, and hope it clears some tombstones - I suspect it will. The next step is to re-model your data so you don't have this problem again in the future.

Comment: Hello Jeff, than you for your answer. I will try to rebuild to index today I will update the post soon as I made some test.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time but ..
After facing the same problem on different cluster there can be multiple source for this type of problem.

It can be because :
- You are deleting / modifying rows at a higher rate than your actual gc_grace and repair combos.
- Compaction can't get thought and your tombstones are never cleared.

Usually this error don't show up if your data model is well structured, most of the time people use Cassandra the same way they'll do with a typical relational database.

Like @JeffJirsa said earlier there is no need to do manual compaction because it will stop the compaction automatically made by Cassandra. TO make them happen again you'll have to restart your node.

The solution here was to lower gc_grace and to do repair more often (should occurs more often that the gc_grace value to avoid problem with resiliency)
Unfortunately, this is not the best solutions which will be to totally remodel the data.